# React withRouter not importing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am importing `withRouter` from `react-router-dom` but the browser shows me the error

> export 'withRouter' (imported as 'withRouter') was not found in
> 'react-router-dom'

I know this is a syntax problem because React has upgraded to newer versions and there should be another replacement called something else instead of `withRouter`. I would appreciate it if anyone know what that new word is called.

Here is a screenshot.
[image]

Comment: which version of `react-router-dom` are you using ?

Comment: According to the [doc](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) you should write `import { withRouter } from "react-router";` and not `import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";`. This hook is part of `react-router`, not `react-router-dom`

Comment: `withRouter` was removed in v6. Please see [the FAQ](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it)

Comment: I tried your version but it says same error when I try to import it from "react-router". I believe that withRouter should be imported from react-router-dom.

Comment: @Nika It was. But it has been removed starting in v6. Run `npm list react-router-dom` and see exactly what version you are running. This is critical context when asking a question about a library.

Comment: I checked my react-router-dom version in package.json and it is 6.2.1 version. React is new to me and it's very confusing. I did read doc but couldn't get how can I use withRouter in new syntax... Thanks for helping btw.

Comment: you must use hooks instead of `withRouter`. You can use `useNavigate`, `useHref`, `useLocation` to get the same behavior

Comment: I got hang of useNavigate and was pretty confident I would do it but I have to do this React Project in old way using classes instead of functional components... I couldn't use useNavigate hook in class component so I am willing to downgrade my react-router-dom version where I could use withRouter and old stuff. So my last question is that can I run downgrade code react-router-dom version from my project's terminal ? while my project is running on localhost ?

Comment: you can downgrade `react-router-dom` from your terminal using `npm install react-router-dom@5.3.0`

Answer (score 1):

`withRouter` is not anymore in `react-router` **v6** (see the [migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#upgrade-to-react-router-v51)).

You must use `hooks` instead :

- [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate)
- [useResolvedPath](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useresolvedpath)
- [useHref](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usehref)
- [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#uselocation)

Comment: You are right, I wasn't aware of a v6 of this library. In the [migration guide](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/upgrading/v5.md) they say `Along with the upgrade to v5.1, you should replace any usage of withRouter with hooks.`

Answer (score 0):

This version doesn't support 'withRouter',instead, you can use some other properties such as useLocation, useNavigate, useParams

,then by using these are you can define 'withRouter ',also avoid to change version of react-router-dom. Use this code for solve the problem

```
import {
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        router={{ location, navigate, params }}
      />
    );
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}
```